# Why would we need to lock a process's address space in RAM?

Tags: c, linux, real-time

http://linux.die.net/man/2/mlockall

> **mlockall**() locks all of the calling process's virtual address space into RAM, preventing that memory from being paged to the swap area.

why is this important in real time systems?

Comment: Also please have a look at Herb Sutter's article at http://www.nwcpp.org/Downloads/2007/Machine_Architecture_-_NWCPP.pdf ....it tells you more about Memory latency issues.....u could consider these while designing a real time system....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It ensures the memory is *always* in RAM and never moved to the swap disk. This makes accessing those memory locations **much** faster as disks are extremely slow compared to RAM.

In a realtime system (linux is NOT a RTS btw!) you need extremely low latencies so a memory access resulting in a disk access is usually not acceptable inside time-critical code.

Comment: Okay, yes, thanks for bolding that statement. So, this means that non-important tasks won't get any place in the ram till this real time thing is active?

Comment: @AnishaKaul: It means that the process will always run with better performance since all the pages associated with that process remain in the RAM.However note that when using `mlockall()` if there is not enough physical memory, memory allocation calls in other processes would fail.

Answer (score 4):

It can be used in real-time applications or high-security data processing for instance.
This is a quote from mlockall() documentation:

> Real-time applications require deterministic timing, and, like
>   scheduling,
>          paging is one major cause of unexpected program execution delays.  Real-time applications will usually also switch to a
>   real-time scheduler with sched_setscheduler(2).   Crypto‐
>          graphic  security  software often handles critical bytes like passwords or secret keys as data structures.  As a result of paging,
>   these secrets could be transferred onto a per‐
>          sistent swap store medium, where they might be accessible to the enemy long after the security software has erased the secrets in
>   RAM and terminated.  (But  be  aware  that  the
>          suspend mode on laptops and some desktop computers will save a copy of the system's RAM to disk, regardless of memory locks.)
>
> Real-time  processes  that  are  using mlockall() to prevent delays on page faults should reserve enough locked stack pages before
>   entering the time-critical section, so that no
>          page fault can be caused by function calls.  This can be achieved by calling a function that allocates a sufficiently large
>   automatic variable (an array) and writes to the  mem‐
>          ory  occupied  by  this array in order to touch these stack pages.  This way, enough pages will be mapped for the stack and can be
>   locked into RAM.  The dummy writes ensure that
>          not even copy-on-write page faults can occur in the critical section.

Comment: thanks much. My fault, I should have read the doc properly before asking.

Answer (score 2):

With *real time* processing the key ingredient is the real time component - i.e. you cannot afford to have to wait from memory to swapped in/out.